# How to deal with blank values in my formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

```
=VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(A7,InventoryLog,5,FALSE),Price_list,IF(Q2InventoryLog!F7="S",2,3),FALSE)
```

I want my function to lookup an Order ID Number and based on that match it to the item name. If the item description is small ("S"), then it should return the price in column 1 and if the item isn't small it should return the item in column 3.

The problem is that sometimes I have a blank row so it throws off everything. So when it's one row behind whenever the blank row appears.

I want my formula to skip rows that are blank, and use the value in the following line. I tried adjusting the IF function but that doesn't work either.

There are 3 possibilites:

```
IF(Q2InventoryLog!F7="L"...), 
IF(Q2InventoryLog!F7="S"...)
IF(Q2InventoryLog!F7=""...)
```

Comment: Please post some sample data to help us understand your problem

Comment: Hii,, @Jaeline nested lookup is very much possible,, but what you trying is,, bit confusing so please [edit] your post & share some sample data wit us,, !

Comment: Sounds like your table array that your lookup formula is referring to is "nonconforming". A conforming table array include each row having data and the leftmost column should be an unique index so that the vlookup works properly. Instead of creating error handling in your formula, I think it would be better to clean up your lookup table array to get rid of blank rows.

Answer (score 0):

So to make your formula tolerant of blank cells we'll use ISBLANK():

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A7), "", VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(A7,InventoryLog,5,FALSE),Price_list,IF(Q2InventoryLog!F7="S",2,3),FALSE))
```

This will return a empty text if A7 is blank. If however you want to return the price for the A8 item instead, you simply have to replace the "" with A8's formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A7), VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(A8,InventoryLog,5,FALSE),Price_list,IF(Q2InventoryLog!F8="S",2,3),FALSE), VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(A7,InventoryLog,5,FALSE),Price_list,IF(Q2InventoryLog!F7="S",2,3),FALSE))
```

Comment: Hey Mobus, thanks for the response. When I do that then I get a back a blank cell, but I want it to return the value in the following cell if the cell is blank

Comment: I also cannot get rid of the blank rows

Comment: Hi I have edited my solution a bit, but I don't think that is really what you want. So is the blanks only in the Q2InventoryLog? Or also in the order ID sheet. Is the Order ID sheet and the Q2InventoryLog in the same order, but Q2InventoryLog has blank rows here and there? So lets say the last orderid is in A15, but Q2InventoryLog has three blank rows dispersed in the data, would that mean the corresponding size info will be in F18?

Comment: Yes the blanks are only in the Q2InventoryLog. 
The Order ID sheet is in the same order as the Q2InventoryLog but the latter has blank rows here and there.
So if the last Order ID in the Order ID sheet is in A15, and the Q2InventoryLog has three blank rows, then the corresponding order id, name of product and size info would be in A18, E18 and F18 in the Q2InventoryLog sheet

Answer (score 0):

I could be way off here (it's happened before...) but reading your formula, it seems to me what you are looking for is not being adequately aimed at in the formula. I read it as:

```
=VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(A7,InventoryLog,5,FALSE),Price_list,IF(Q2InventoryLog!F7="S",2,3),FALSE)
```

`VLOOKUP(A7,InventoryLog,5,FALSE:`  A7 has some Order ID Number and the lookup uses it to find an ItemName in column 5 of the record it finds in InventoryLog.

Then the external lookup uses that Item Name to find a record in the Price_list and, based upon the row in Q2InventoryLog, returns column 2 or 3 from that record in Price_list.

Logically, the question arises as to just WHY F7 should be the row having the record that A7 needs? Obviously, it might have no connection:  you had "7" on the mind and just typed "F" and "7" But why then, "F", and how would we usefully know what to find? Perhaps Q2InventoryLog is supposed to match InventoryLog line by line and does that VERY well (or... this would be rather pointless after the data got used, then updated, a few times!) EXCEPT that now and then, blank lines sneak in for whatever reason.

Knowing why the records match (why F7 is the cell to HARDCODE into this, and not some other cell) is not addressed in your question. You do seem to be asking it again and again with more detail each time, so maybe you will address that in the next iteration. And someone can give you more on-point help, slicker help. Less broad. But until then, I'll give two pointers:

1. You might want to try to organize the Q2InventoryLog data in a way that includes either the Item Name the inner lookup finds, or the Order ID Number that starts it all (the first would be the gold standard in a way as it would be "better" data (not least due to it being more broadly useful), but the second would be a perfectly valid approach as one would suspect the data "on the ground" here would include sizing info in the order-related information though it does not necessarily work in the more general version of your issue). But if either, you could use a second internal lookup to find the exact record and choose data the column F7 represents happens to contain and use it in your `IF()` test.
2. You could use some effort to clean the data of the blank lines. I do NOT NOT NOT mean traditional data cleansing or hunting down why the Q2InventoryLog data gets blank rows inserted into it. Presumably, if you wanted to, or could, do that, you would and the problem would be gone (well, waiting to spring itself on you at a bad moment).

What I mean is to do something quite simple. Use `FILTER()` to simply filter out the blank rows. Not use Excel's filtering functionality as it would conserve the row addresses and still need more work to work for this. But simply `FILTER()` the actual Q2InventoryLog data set with a simple "something <> blank" condition so it leaves out the difficulty-causing blank lines. Since the Q2InventoryLog data seems as if it is supposed to otherwise match one to one, that would do the trick. In your lookup, use the table/range that `FILTER()` produces instead of the actual data.

A simplistic version of the `FILTER()` function in use this way might be:

(Say the record is C7:F7 in Q2InventoryLog and whole rows are blank, not just some cells in a row. So if C12 is blank, the whole row is a problem and needs removed because the data needed in row 12 is currently in row 13 and would move up to the right row if row 12 went away. Also, let's say the data is in C3:F27.)

```
=FILTER(C3:F27,C3:C27<>"")
```

Obviously, you'd adapt that to fit your data.

A point to take away in the above is that a problem can sometimes be approached on a different conceptual path and have an easy solution. Instead of figuring out how to make the formula know to jump down a row (one row the first time, then on all succeeding lookups below that point until another blank row occurs after which all must know to jump down, and not just the one row, but two now, until...), figure out how to make the problem-causing rows go away. And if you do that and, like here, maybe only see bothersome data cleansing or arguments with the source of the data as the only ways to do that, it might turn out, like here, there's yet another way to do it without that work or those arguments.

Finally, if there isn't really a one-to-one correspondence with unfortunately inserted random blank rows messing things up, well, this won't solve things (mmm... unless it turns out you CAN use the Q2InventoryLog structure to support that extra internal lookup). So you'll need to try asking again...

If so, try forgetting the phone company technology approach of one teensy improvement at a time, then years of earning off it, then adding another teensy improvement and just give full information. You will find that much more immediately helpful TO YOU.

Comment: Really appreciate the feedback @Jeorje. 

I have a listing of Order IDs in a separate sheet. I need to map those order IDs to the name of the product and the size of the product in a table that is found in the InventoryLog sheet. However, in this sheet, there is a line that is blank and I can't remove it due to the requirements of the activity.

After I get both the product name and size, then I have to find the price of the item, "S" or "L" in a separate table.